# Textview color from another Textview Value - Android

Tags: android, colors, textview

I have 2 textviews for color and hex. The Hex is for the string value and the Color is for the color. When I input the hex string value the color textview changes color. I use this but I get error in background color.

color.setBackgroundColor(result);

Comment: What exactly is the error? Some logcat would be helpful

Comment: @jandroid : see answers below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `Color.parseColor(String hexColor)` :

```
String hexColor = "#" + rMeans + gMeans + bMeans;
color.setBackgroundColor(Color.parse(hexColor));
```

Comment: You're awesome/ Thank You :* Check for you!

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get a color int from a hex string:

```
color.setBackgroundColor(Color.parse("#" + result));
```

Note the `#` is only necessary if the hex string is not already starting with an `#`.

Comment: I'm getting the hex string value from this   result.setText("#" + rMeans + gMeans + bMeans);